# Why window is nil in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I need to present view controller from the `AppDelegate`, so I wrote the following code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let authViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as ViewController
if let keyWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
    keyWindow.rootViewController = authViewController
}
```

Unfortunately, `window` and `keyWindow` are both `nil`. Why?

Comment: When is this code being executed?

Comment: @jrturton This is code is execute in the `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool` function

Comment: Ok, in that function your app won't have a window unless you've made one manually, or you've set a storyboard or xib as the launch interface. Have you done that?

Comment: @jrturton No. How can I do it via Interface Builder?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to create the window yourself in `AppDelegate` if not using the main interface option:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
```

**Swift 3.0+**

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

Then call your code above, using `window`.

Finally, call `makeKeyAndVisible()` on the window.

Comment: I don't want to automatically load the initial view controller, because I need to present either authorization view controller or the main view controller manually

Comment: Thanks for the answer! btw, `window` doesn't have `makeKeyAndOrderFront` function

Comment: It works as expected without `makeKeyAndVisible` function call too. Is it necessary?

Comment: It was always there on the templates so I assumed so. Don't know.

Comment: **for Swift 5** `self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)`